# how to remove sessionID:null value objects from the array nested inside the array of objects in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb, object

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5edfb4e587a1873120735dcf",
        "firstname": "abc",
        "lastname": "abc",
        "sessions": [
            {
                "_id": "5efc68d146d8330a449e7108",
                "sessionID": null
            },
            {
                "_id": "5efc68e646d8330a449e710a",
                "sessionID": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5eedf5685bdb7d33c83186e7",
        "firstname": "sam",
        "lastname": "ple",
        "sessions": [
            {
                "_id": "5efc692d46d8330a449e710c",
                "sessionID": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5ef04df83e41dd5b78fe6908",
        "firstname": "User",
        "lastname": "name1",
        "sessions": [
            {
                "_id": "5efc6a8846d8330a449e710e",
                "sessionID": null
            },
            {
                "_id": "5efc6abd46d8330a449e7110",
                "sessionID": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "5efe0d0c7300073244d765d9",
        "sessions": [],
        "firstname": "User",
        "lastname": "name1"
    }
]
```

Comment: -Do you need a mongo query / javascript code?
-& add what output you need.so i will give the answer

Comment: i am using :- artists = await Artist.find({}).populate({
            path:'sessions.sessionID',
            populate:{
                path:'agency',
                select:'_id firstname lastname'
            },
            match:filterObj
        }).select('_id firstname lastname sessions').limit(limit).skip(startIndex) to fetch the data and it is returning the data mentioned in the question....i don;t want null values after population.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map over your array and filter out sessions with null

```
let originalArray = [
    {
        "_id": "5edfb4e587a1873120735dcf",
        "firstname": "abc",
        "lastname": "abc",
        "sessions": [
            {
                "_id": "5efc68d146d8330a449e7108",
                "sessionID": null
            },
            {
                "_id": "5efc68e646d8330a449e710a",
                "sessionID": null
            }
        ]
    },
    .... the rest of your orignal object
]

let newArray = originalArray.map(item => {
    let sessions = item.sessions.filter(session => {
        return session.sessionID !== null
    })

    return {
        ...item,
        sessions
    }
})
```